# In xterm the numpad 1 and 7 buttons does not work properly

Tags: linux, xterm, numpad

I use VNC, open an xterm, and for example when I press "NumPad7", it completes "Home" command.  Also "NumPad1" is mapped to "End". How to fix this?

In fact there is a code for .cshrc that does the work required. But unfortunately I can't translate it into a bash code. Please help me to translate. Here is the code:

```
if ($?TERM) then
    # fix the home, end, ins and del keys
    if ($TERM == "xterm" || $TERM == "vt100" || \
        $TERM == "vt102" || $TERM !~ "con*") then
        # bind keypad keys for xterm, vt100, vt102, console
        bindkey "\e[1~" beginning-of-line  # Home
        bindkey "\e[7~" beginning-of-line  # Home rxvt
        bindkey "\e[2~" overwrite-mode     # Ins
        bindkey "\e[3~" delete-char        # Delete
        bindkey "\e[4~" end-of-line        # End
        bindkey "\e[8~" end-of-line        # End rxvt
    endif
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`numlockx`](http://ktown.kde.org/~seli/numlockx/). It can set or toggle the state of numlock from the command line. To turn on numlock:

```
numlockx on
```

Now when you press NumPad7, for example, you'll get a 7.

It's available in these popular formats as well as at the link above:

- [rpm](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=numlockx)
- [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=numlockx)
- [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=numlockx&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @Narek: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: No, the problem is that my numpad is ON, and the other numbers work correctly. Only 1 and 7 do not work.

Comment: @Narek: That's really weird. Try running `xev` and see if the output looks right. Check to see if something strange has been set using `xmodmap`.